# Create a vector of different sequence repeated with runif and rnorm

Tags: r, vector, random, difference, seq

I want to do something like :

```
vector <-  c(runif(3),rnorm(1), runif(3), rnorm(1))
```

I've tried :

```
vector <- rep( c(runif(3), rnorm(1) ), times = 2) )
```

But the problem is that it's two times the same sequence.

If you can help me please.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what `replicate` is meant for.
From the `help('replicate')` page (my emphasis):

> `replicate` is a wrapper for the common use of `sapply` for repeated evaluation of an expression (which will usually involve **random number generation**).

```
set.seed(1234)
vector <-  replicate(2, c(runif(3),rnorm(1)))
vector
#          [,1]        [,2]
#[1,] 0.1137034 0.640310605
#[2,] 0.6222994 0.009495756
#[3,] 0.6092747 0.232550506
#[4,] 0.3143686 0.429124689
```

**Edit**

After the explanation in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61368944/create-a-vector-of-different-sequence-repeated-with-runif-and-rnorm/61369059#comment108564756_61369059), I believe the follwing is closer to what the question asks for. Note that each matrix 2x2 has the elements in the previous output in the correct order.

```
set.seed(1234)
W <- array(dim = c(2, 2, 2))
W[] <- replicate(2, c(runif(3), rnorm(1)))
W
#, , 1
#
#          [,1]      [,2]
#[1,] 0.1137034 0.6092747
#[2,] 0.6222994 0.3143686
#
#, , 2
#
#            [,1]      [,2]
#[1,] 0.640310605 0.2325505
#[2,] 0.009495756 0.4291247
```

Comment: this won't scale well, because it won't fully vectorize the random draws -- for 2 replications it'll be fine, but if we do 1e6 replications, we're doing an R loop 1e6 times when it would be better to let C handle that loop all at once

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by filling declaring the full vector first, then filling the indices for each distribution at once:

```
out_length = 4L * 2L
# every fourth element will come from rnorm; the rest from runif
norm_idx = seq(4L, out_length, by = 4L)
n_norm = length(norm_idx)

# declare output
out = numeric(out_length)
out[norm_idx] = rnorm(n_norm)
out[-norm_idx] = runif(out_length - n_norm)
```

---

Alternatively, here's a tricky way to accomplish this using matrix indexing:

```
set.seed(394839)
m = matrix(0, nrow = 4L, ncol = 2L)

m[1:3, ] = runif(3L * ncol(m))
m[4L,  ] = rnorm(ncol(m))

c(m)
# [1]  0.4478556  0.1336022  0.5860134 -0.1626707  0.7055598  0.7631879  0.3132743  1.5485366
```

in R, matrices are just vectors with dimensions, and they filled column-by-column -- hence we can declare this matrix:

```
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    3    5    7    9
# [2,]    2    4    6    8   10
```

like this:

```
matrix(1:10, nrow = 2L, ncol = 5L)
```

with that in mind, we can replicate your 3-1-3-1 pattern by making 3-1 be the pattern within each column.

You can confirm it's working by scaling up (so small sample effects are muted):

```
nrep = 1e4
set.seed(39893)
m = matrix(0, nrow = 4L, ncol = nrep)

m[1:3, ] = runif(3L * nrep)
m[4L,  ] = rnorm(nrep)

out = c(m)

idx = seq(4L, length(out), by = 4L)

plot(density(out[idx]), main = 'Normally distributed')
plot(density(out[-idx]), main = 'Uniformly distributed')
```

Comment: Thank you, the thing is : this vector is for a matrix. I can explain : 
I have a matrix W <- array ( vector, c( 2, 2, 2) )
And I want that 3 of my vector be runif and 1 rnorm, on the two dim. I want to do this on a proper way if its possible.

Comment: @GuillaumePech even better -- you can use my approach, but instead of matrix indexing, just use array indexing directly, e.g. `W[ , , 1] = runif(prod(dim(W)[1:2]))`, things along those lines -- no need to convert back to the `out` vector